# Use column in 3rd level sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

How can I use a column from the top level `SELECT` in the 3rd level sub query?

I tried this but its gives: `unknown column foo.id`

```
SELECT foo.id,
       (
           SELECT SUM(bar.amount)
           FROM bar
           JOIN (
               SELECT DISTINCT ding.id
               FROM baz
               JOIN ding ON ding.baz_id = baz.id
               WHERE baz.foo_id = foo.id
           ) AS j ON j.id = bar.id
       ) AS amount
FROM foo
```

Comment: Try removing the comma after amount.

Answer (score 2):

Try
    SELECT foo_id

```
FROM (
       SELECT SUM(bar.amount),j.foo_id
       FROM bar
       JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT ding.id,baz.foo_id
           FROM baz
           JOIN ding ON ding.baz_id = baz.id
       ) AS j ON j.id = bar.id
   ) AS amount;
```